# EJB - Pass Contextual Data from JSF to EJB

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

A have a new feature that forces me to pass some new data structure to my EJBs.

This is a user session context that has some information about the current user.

How can I pass this data to my EJBs without refactoring my method signature and calls?

Use ThreadLocal? But if it is not on the same JVM?

There's some code bellow. Can you have a tip to me?

```
/** created at login time, when user put it's credential */
public class UserSessionContext {
    private User current;
    private Company company;
    // getters e setters
}

/** web page controller */
@ManagedBean // at web tier
public class ListCustomersController {

    @EJB
    CustomersRepository customers; // some remote interface

    // getters / setters
    private List<Filters> filters; // from the UI

    /** used in a datatable component */
    public List<Customer> getAll(){
        return customers.getAllWith(filters); // I have no UserSessionContext parameter
    }

}

/** used by web controller */
@Stateless
public CustomersEJB implements CustomersRepository {

    @Inject 
    UserSessionContext currentContext; // injected before call this object

    public List<Customer> getAllWith(List<Filter> filters){

        TypeQuery<Customer> customersQuery = ... //
        customersQuery.setParameter("company",currentContext.getCompany());

        return customersQuery.getResultList();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard mechanism for doing this ([JSR-149](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=149)).  WebSphere Application Server has a [Work Area Service](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/workarea/concepts/cwa_overview.html) programming model extension that can be used to propagate contexts in this manner.